# Python Quits on Lion after running Google App Engine App

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, python-2.7, osx-lion

I've been trying to use GOOGLE APP ENGINE LAUNCHER (PHP environment) for testing the simple HELLOWORLD APP but as soon as I hit the "run" button, a message says "Python unexpectedly Quit"...

The Log Console shows:

```
*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8000
Python command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
INFO     2013-10-01 13:10:06,504 devappserver2.py:660] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2013-10-01 13:10:06,551 api_server.py:327] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-10-01 13:10:06,565 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49313
INFO     2013-10-01 13:10:06,579 dispatcher.py:168] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-10-01 13:10:06,593 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-10-01 13:10:06,923 php_runtime.py:223] The PHP runtime is not available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 219, in new_instance
    self._check_environment(php_executable_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 171, in _check_environment
    version_stdout))
_PHPEnvironmentError: "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi -v" returned an error [-11]
```

I guess the issue has to do with the last statement...
_PHPEnvironmentError: "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php-cgi -v" returned an error [-11]
...as Python crashes as soon as it reaches this line...

I tried installing Python from Macports and from the Python site so I must have more than one installation on my computer.

On my Google App Engine Launcher Preferences I put:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

The os is Lion 10.7.5

Can anyone advice?

Thanks!!!

Luiz